# Does salesforce supports Live Streaming in Chatter?

Tags: chatter

If I posted something on a User's page, does salesforce.com has this functionality to pop-up this chatter activity on my page or it will automatically display that Chatter activity without manual refreshing my page.

Comment: for clarity, I think it is fair to assume that you are referring to salesforce through a web browser, however, just in case, you might want to state what type of chatter feed you mean, e.g., is it iOS Salesforce1 app, android etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an auto refresh going on in the background which shows a prompt saying New Activity which the user can click on to refresh the page with the latest chatter activity.

For desktop notifications use Chatter Desktop.

If you meant the Streaming API then that isn't supported for Chatter Objects today.